# Scala Regex group in match case

Tags: scala

I have a regualar Expression like this

```
private val operatorCallS = """(CALL) (?:\$([0-9][0-9]?)) (\w+)"""
private val operatorCall= operatorCallS.r
```

then i have a match like this:

```
if (tokens.hasNext) {
  tokens.next() match {    
    case opeatorCall(m) => ...
```

Here I want the group with the numbers but `m.group()` doesn't work, this function doesn't exist. why?

Answer (score 0):

Because m is not a Regex but a parse result (String) of application of operatorCall which is Regex.
In order to parse token (tokens.next()) you can use the following code:

```
val token = "CALL $12 aaa"
token match {
  case operatorCall(m, m2, m3) => println(m); println(m2); println(m3)
  case _ => println("No")
}
```